# single cell background color in WPF Datagrid not all row color

Tags: c#, wpf, cell, background-color, wpfdatagrid

I have write this code to change the color of a cell in WPF mydatagrid, but as result i have all the row colored and i don't know why.

```
Style style = this.FindResource("backColor") as Style;
DataGridClientFile.CellStyle = style;


<Style x:Key="backColor" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Colore}" Value="Red">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Colore}" Value="Green">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Colore}" Value="Yellow">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Colore}" Value="Cyan">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Colore}" Value="White">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Comment: You set the `CellStyle` property of the `DataGrid` itself, don't you? To which cell do you expect your style to be applied? A `DataGridColumn` has a `CellStyle` property that can used to change the style of cells in that particular column if that's what you want.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what i needed. thank you.

Comment: Why you don't use converters to convert a string to Color

Comment: Yep! Good Question. The main problem is that i am having some problems with understanding the DataContext. I created a class for the rows in the datagrid, then i created a modelview class with iNotifyPropertyChanged and Binded it to the DataGrid. Ok i t works, because i set the datacontext via C# in code behind. I cannot set the datacontext on XAML and i cannot understand how to convert only the columns i need.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution :

```
Style style = this.FindResource("backColor") as Style;
Style styleNX = this.FindResource("backColorNX") as Style;
if (DataGridClientFile.Columns.Count >= 14)
            {
                DataGridColumn col = DataGridClientFile.Columns[14];
                col.CellStyle = style;
                DataGridColumn colNX = DataGridClientFile.Columns[15];
                colNX.CellStyle = styleNX;
            }
```